# Elasticsearch nested data types - Is the nested object still visible in the original document?

Tags: elasticsearch

When reading about nested data types, they say each nested object is saved as a "separate hidden document". Does this mean when I create fieldName1 as type nested. The following search will no longer work?

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "type": {
            "value": "typeName"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "fieldName1.@description": "keyword"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "fieldName1.#text": "foo"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, I have a database but no nested types, I want to include nested portions for fieldName1 to refine particular searches that "foo" as a keyword but I do not want to lose the functionality I currently have.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you modify the mapping of `fieldName1` to `nested` your query will need to be changed to use a different syntax:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "type": {
            "value": "typeName"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "fieldName1",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "fieldName1.@description": "keyword"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "fieldName1.#text": "foo"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The source documents that will be returned will still contain the nested `fieldName1` data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So if I understand correctly, if I do not modify my search, documents will still contain the nested fieldName1 data. If i want to refine the search, I can then use "nested": { "path": ... query?